# Cancel AsyncTask when getting any exception

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to display a Dialog when any exception occurs in `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`. I know I can't display a dialog while previous task is running. So for this I tried to Cancel (finish) `AsyncTask` like this,

```
try {
    response= HttpService.doServerRequest(params);          
} catch(Exception e){
    task.cancel(true);    //Cancelling AsyncTask
    CustomException.onException(CurrentActivityName.this);          
}
```

I have created a `CustomException` class for handling all exceptions and for displaying a dialog that will tell some error has occurred. I know this type of question is  already asked here but I am not getting any solution that's why I am asking.

Is there any way to finish all previous activity or finish `AsyncTask` ?

Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Finishing the `AsyncTask` from inside the `AsyncTask` or from somewhere else?

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon/2034238#2034238) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+exit+an+android+app)

Comment: @FD_ : Inside `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Stopping an `AsyncTask` from inside is quite easy:

```
HTTPResponse response = null;
try {
    response = HttpService.doServerRequest(params);          
} catch(Exception e){         
} 

if (response == null) return null;
```

You simply have to return null, or any other object that you can use to tell in `onPostExecute()` whether the task was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

1.finish all previous activity
you just call finish method !or set the activity as a singleton mode (actually, I do not clear what your mean)

2.if your want  finish AsyncTask . 
 you should note that AsyncTask in different Android version has different features

> > below 4.0.x AsyncTask task.cancel method cant stop the AsyncTask running , It just set a flag as ture ,and nothing , your should get the flag value ,and decide what to do, for example :

```
 task.cancel(true);

   if(task.iscancel()){
       CustomException.onException(CurrentActivityName.this)
      // or other stuff ,what you want !
    }
```

> > above 4.0.x It will work exactly ! if you call task.cancel(true); the task will stop running

Comment: An error occurred while executing doingInBackground()

Comment: can you describe the detail what you have done ? or paste a error log